# ASPNETCORE 2.0 not picking up system-wide Environment variable

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a boilerplate AspNetCore 2.0 MVC Web App setup.  The app itself runs fine.

But I can't seem to get my app in IIS (not IIS express) to pick up my System Environment Variable.

Steps I took:

1. I published the web app to a random folder on my machine.
2. I setup a new site in IIS with typical settings (e.g., port 8080, no managed code app pool, etc.)
3. I gave the publish folder the correct IIS_IUSRS security permissions.
4. I have the AspNetCore module/handler setup in IIS to handle these core web apps.
5. I went to my System settings and added system-wide Env variable   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development.  See screenshot below.
6. Web config does not have any environment variables in it.

[image: screenshot]

App loads fine in my browser.

But it still thinks it's Production.  It's like it doesn't see or care about the environment setting I have globally.  I thought the environment variables beat out all other settings. This is not one of those temporary, console lifetime-only environment settings.

I tried recycling the app pool and restarting the website.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  I forgot that you have to reboot the system for a system-wide variable to take hold.  An app pool recycle and site restart was not enough.